# New Tab Traffic in Google Analytics - Not Direct , Why?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, tracking, referrals

I'm testing Google Analytics in order to Track traffic from Facebook Posts to my personale Website.

When i click on a Facebook Post a New Tab Page is opened without UTM parameters.

I was sure that this type of page is Collected as "direct traffic" in Google Analytics but, opening the http /collect something strange happens.

The *referral* parameters is "www.facebook.com" (why? New Tab is usually with no referral -> Direct Traffic) and in Google Analytics a *Social Traffic* Session is collected.

I don't understand why.

Comment: Why should such a new tab not have a referral? It *is not*  “direct traffic”, if I used a _link_ to open this page in the new tab. // The [`Referrer-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) header allows site to specify in more detail if/how they want the browser to send a referrer. The value `origin` achieves what you see here, quote from MDN: _“Only send the origin of the document as the referrer in all cases. The document `https://example.com/page.html` will send the referrer `https://example.com/`”_

Comment: In addition to this direct traffic, by its nature, doesn't have a medium, so it wouldn't override the medium of a still-active Session.